# How to use boolean value from other entity in activitydesktopview entity?

Tags: guidewire, gosu, claimcenter

I am working on adding a new column in activitydesktopview that shows the value from claim entity.
For example, I want to display claim.Indicator.Ison and check if the activity has any document attached. I tried using Activity.Documents.hasElements or Documents.isEmpty but they did not work.

I get an error message saying the specified path is not valid. How can I add these values directly in activitydesktopview entity?

I know I can use enhancement property but that is not a proper way to do it.

Comment: I think from the answers below the general consensus is that it is possible to do this, likely with a denorm column added to the Activity entity, but this solution is not very elegant and adds yet another denorm column to the data model which could become out of sync with the underlying normalized data. I think the best solution would be to go back to the business and understand why they want to see an indicator of "1 or more documents" linked to an activity on the Desktop page. If I was working on this problem I would strongly push back due to the suboptimal technical solutions available.

Answer (score 4):

`ActivityDesktopView` is a view entity and the dot notation `Activity.Documents` is trying to traverse an array. If you are using the `viewEntityColumn` sub-element then it does not allow traversing arrays and hence the error. This is mentioned in the [View Entities Documentation](https://docs.guidewire.com/cloud/bc/202310/config/config/topics/r_dz3181928.html) (Requires Login).

> The path attribute definition cannot traverse arrays.
>
> The path attribute is always relative to the primary entity on which
> you base the view.

I figured that the `computedcolumn` sub-element doesn't allow traversing arrays either and the other way to deduce this would be using something like the below on the boolean cell of the list view or through an enhancement property like you mentioned.

`ActivityDesktopView.Activity.Documents.Count > 0`

Comment: Please don't do what is described in the last sentence of this answer.  Adding "dot paths" to cell contents, particularly in a Desktop list view, is a certain performance issue.  Any one usage may be tolerable, but following this as a pattern will cause issues.  In this particular expression, each cell will load the Activity bean, then load all the Document beans, then return the number of Documents.  Also, pcf rendering often evaluates expressions multiple times, so this may happen 2 or 3 times.  Don't use dot expressions in list view cells.

Comment: Totally agree with Martin that the dot path approach is crude and non-performant and should be avoided in this particular scenario. It’s better to go with a de-normalized column as suggested by Enrique in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something else you could explore is to denormalize the value of the property you are looking for in preupdate rules (ActivityPreupdate in this case), and after that you could add a viewEntityColumn in your viewEntity for the denormalized column, accessible directly as a field from Activity (something like Activity.ActivityDocumentCountDenorm_Ext or Activity.ActivityHasDocumentsDenorm_Ext).
I would recommend against this solution if the primary entity for the view entity was Claim (for performance reasons, since it probably has more frequent changes and more Preupdate rules to evaluate) but for Activity it might be a suitable solution.